# Application of the baraita about "Don't profane daughter for Zenut" Leviticus 19:29 reported in Sanhredin 76a?

Tags: halacha, sexuality, talmud-bavli, maseches-sanhedrin, arayot

I'm an Italian Noahide.

The topic in question manifests my purely intellectual interest, concerning the Jews and not the Gentiles.

We read in Talmud Bavli-Sanhredrin 76a (English translation from “The William Davidson Talmud”):

> Rabbi Ya’akov, brother of Rav Aḥa bar Ya’akov (…):Is taught in a
>   baraita: With regard to the verse (Leviticus 19:29): “Do not profane
>   your daughter by causing her to act licentiously(lehaznotah),” one
>   might have thought that it is with regard to a priest who marries his
>   daughter to a Levite or Israelite that the verse is speaking, since
>   marrying an Israelite disqualifies her from partaking of teruma. To
>   counter this, the verse states “by causing her to act
>   licentiously,”indicating that it is with regard to profaning that
>   involves licentiousness that the verse is speaking. **The reference is
>   to one who gives his daughter to a man for the purpose of intercourse
>   that is not for the sake of marriage.”**

If the English translation is accurate (I am unable to consult the original text) it would seem, if I am not mistaken, that the expression in this baraita  **"intercourse that** **is not for the sake of marriage"** refers to any intercourse consumed outside the marriage relationship.

I would like to know if there are more limited  interpretations in the Jewish tradition about such specific  expression, referring only  to the hypothesis of casual/promiscuous sex (paid or not), or sexual intercourse consumed between an unmarried woman and a man she can’t halachically  marry (therefore with reference to a woman "zonah" in the strictly legal  sense, also considering that " lehaznotah " has the same linguistic root, if I am not mistaken, of "zonah").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ramban explains אל תחלל את בתך להזנותה to refer to relationship for which there is no *Kiddushin* (Halachic marriage) possible, for example a Canaanite slave or a *goi*; see Malbim Leviticus 19:29 who explains:

> הרמב"ן השיג על רש"י שפירש שמוסרה אליו שלא לשם אישות דאם כן אתיא כר' אליעזר דסבר פנוי הבא על הפנויה עשאה זונה ולא קיי"ל כוותיה. ועל כן פירש שמדבר אם מסרה למי שאין קדושין תופסין בה והולך לשיטתו שחולק עם הרמב"ם (במנין המצות ס' שנה ובחבורו ריש הל' אישות) על הבא על הפנויה דרך זנות. ולהרמב"ן קאי על מי שאין קדושין תופסין כגון עבד
>
> Rashi says the Passuk is refering to someone who gives his daughter not for the sake of marriage to someone else who is not forbidden to her. Ramban says however this only fits with the opinion of the Tanna Rabbi Elazar who says a non-matrimonial relationship makes a woman forbidden to a Cohen as a *Zonah*. However since we hold like the Rabanan (whosay out of wedlock relations with a Kosher Jew do not render a woman unfit to marry a Kohen)  the correct interpretation of the Passuk is not to give ones unmarried daughter to a Slave or others whom there is no *Kiddushin* to her and thus renders her a Zonah unfit to marry a Cohen.

The Targum Onkles seems to (a bit like the Ramban) understand the passuk meaning giving ones daughter to a Gentile who will lead his daughter astray (see targum [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.7.4?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=Onkelos%20Deuteronomy&lang2=he) using the same language) for meaning of Taus which will lead her astray away from the Torah and Mitzvos

> לָא תַחֵיל יָת בְּרַתָּךְ לְאַטְעָיוּתַהּ וְלָא תִטְעֵי אַרְעָא וְתִתְמְלֵי אַרְעָא עֵיצַת חֲטִאין
>
> Do not profane your daughter (in marriage) to lead her astray from Hashem, and the land shall not go astray and be filled with sinful thoughts .

Note the Semag ([Rav Moshe Micoucy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Jacob_of_Coucy), 13th century) Asei 48 and Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer 2,9 are of the opinion that אל תחלל את בתך להזנותה refers to the father to give his daughter to an Old man for marriage (as a prevention of *eishes Ish* because of her discontent with the forced marriage imposed by her father to an old man when she was not yet a *Bogeres*) like Rabbi Eliezer (not rabbi Elazar) says in Sanhedrin 76a.

Comment: Could you please give me the translation of Leviticus 19:29 present in  Targum Onkelos?

Comment: @Amos74 yes i have translated the Targum who seems to agree with the ramban that the Passuk is refering to marrying a *Goi* for which there is no *Kiddushin*, but unlike the Ramban the Targum gives the reason being that she will be led astray by her spouse

Comment: Could you write here the exact English version of the Onkelos translation? Thanks a lot, and sorry fot the disturb

Comment: @Amos74 i've put the words that are implicit in the context but not explicit in bracket

Comment: @Amos74 see Yevamot 16a ורבי יהודה מטמא מפני שהם גרים ו**טועים** מבין העובדי כוכבים טהורים והוינן בה

And Rabbi Yehuda deems it ritually impure because those residents of that place are converts and are **in error. In other words, some of the inhabitants of Rekem assimilated and no longer observe the halakhot of the Torah** here is a proof from the soncino translation of the Talmud that the word טְעֵ means to be led astray or assimilate if you don'tbelieve me